# Pointer not updating in main

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a main program in another file calling a function `cbuf_update()` that in turn calls `cbuf_sizeChange()`  Here is what is confusing me: Within `cbuf_update`, calling `cbuf_sizeChange` properly updates `cb_ptr`, but in main.c, it is garbage from when I freed cb1 in `sizeChange()`.  I cannot make it static because there are a variable number of cbufs in main.  What do I do?  I cannot change the signature of `cbuf_update()`.

Struct def:

```
typedef struct cbuf {
    unsigned int max;
    unsigned int start;
    unsigned int end;
    unsigned int size;
    quote *quotes;
} cbuf;
```

Call from main.c:

```
cbuf *eur_jpy;
eur_usd = cbuf_init() ;
cbuf_update(eur_jpy, time, rate) ;
```

Relevant methods in other file:

```
cbuf * cbuf_init()
{
    //initialize the cbuf with malloc

    return cb1;
}

void cbuf_update(cbuf *cb_ptr, double rate)
{
    cb_ptr = cbuf_sizeChange(cb_ptr, 2);
}

cbuf *cbuf_sizeChange(cbuf *cb1, double factor)
{
        cbuf *cb2;
    quote *quotes;
    quotes = (quote *)malloc(cb1->max * factor * sizeof(quote));
    cb2 = (cbuf *)malloc(sizeof(*quotes) + 4 * sizeof(unsigned int));

        //Update quotes here(exluding it)

        cb2->size = cb1->size;
    cb2->end = cb1->size - 1;
    cb2->max = factor * cb1->max;
    cb2->start = 0;
    free(cb1->quotes);
    free(cb1);

    cb2->quotes = quotes;

    return cb2;
}
```

Comment: Your mallocs for cb1 and cb2 are wrong. You don't allocate memory for structs by adding up all the sizes of the elements; you just do sizeof on the whole struct.  You also don't need to cast the return value of malloc, and it can mask errors if you do.

So you just need something like cb1 = malloc(sizeof(cbuf)); or arguably even better cb1 = malloc(sizeof(*cb1));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit doesn't look right:

```
void cbuf_update(cbuf *cb_ptr, double rate)
{
    cb_ptr = cbuf_sizeChange(cb_ptr, 2);
}
```

It modifies `cb_ptr`, which is a local copy of whatever you passed into `cbuf_update()` as the first parameter.

You might want to think along these lines:

```
void cbuf_update(cbuf **cb_ptr, double rate)
{
    *cb_ptr = cbuf_sizeChange(*cb_ptr, 2);
}
```

and instead of calling `cbuf_update(something, rate)` call `cbuf_update(&something, rate)`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I cannot change the signatures of cbuf_update.  It needs to run with the main I'm given.

Comment: OK, then how about updating `cb1->everything` in `cbuf_sizeChange()` and returning that same `cb1`? It doesn't look like you really need `cb2` there.

Comment: I need to malloc a new cb1 and free the old one.  How would that look?

Comment: Why do you need to free the original one? How a different `struct cbuf` is better than the one you've already got? To me it looks like all you need to do is `free(cb1->quotes); cb1->quotes = malloc(...);` and then update the rest of `cb1->...` and return `cb1`.

Comment: There's no way to do what you want without changing the signature of cbuf_update.  There seems no good reason to allocate a complete new cbuf inside cbuf_sizeChange.  Assuming this is some kind of assignment I'd suggest you look at the question and/or instructions again and see if that is really a requirement.