# C segfaults when allocating memory that has been freed

Tags: c, arrays

I am working on a program that uses a circular buffer to store stock quotes. The buffer has to be able to expand and shrink depending on whether or not certain conditions are met during each update of the buffer. However, I am having an issue where I can expand the buffer once, but after that if I try to expand it again I get segfaults. I am using a new buffer and assigning it to the old one after freeing the memory that the old buffer was using. My code is as follows.

```
cbuf* cbuf_init(){

    cbuf *buffer = malloc(sizeof(cbuf) + 9 * sizeof(quote));
    buffer->currSize = 0;
    buffer->maxSize = startSize;
    buffer->start = 0;
    buffer->end = 0;
    buffer->freeSlots = startSize;
    return buffer;
}


void cbuf_update(cbuf *cb_ptr, unsigned int time, double rate){
    int threeFourths;    
    threeFourths = (3 * cb_ptr->maxSize)/4;


    if(cb_ptr->freeSlots == 0){
        printf("\n\nEXPANDING CIRCULAR BUFFER!\n\n");

        int newSize;
        newSize = (cb_ptr->maxSize * 2) - 1;
        printf("Newsize: %d\n", newSize);
        cbuf *newBuffer = malloc(sizeof(cbuf) + newSize * sizeof(quote));
        printf("pastthe malloc\n");
        newBuffer->maxSize = cb_ptr->maxSize * 2;
        newBuffer->start = cb_ptr->start;
        newBuffer->end = cb_ptr->end;
        newBuffer->freeSlots = newBuffer->maxSize - cb_ptr->maxSize;

        int x;
        int counter;
        counter = 0;

        for(x = cb_ptr->end; x < cb_ptr->maxSize; x ++){
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].time;
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[x].rate;
            counter ++;
        }
        int y;
        for(y = 0; y < cb_ptr->start; y ++){
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].time = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].time;
            newBuffer->quoteBuffer[counter].rate = cb_ptr->quoteBuffer[y].rate;
            counter++;
        }
        newBuffer->start = cb_ptr->maxSize;
        newBuffer->end = 0;
        printf("newBuffer start: %d\n", newBuffer->start);
        free(cb_ptr);
        *cb_ptr = *newBuffer;


    }   



}
```

and my main is:

```
int main(){

    cbuf *cb1 ;
    cb1 = cbuf_init() ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 60, 1.291) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 63, 1.287) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 63, 1.231) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 69, 1.229) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 72, 1.247) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1,361,1.291);
    cbuf_update(cb1, 411, 1.291) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 412, 1.281) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 413, 1.292) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 414, 1.284) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 414, 1.290) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 511, 1.241) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 512, 1.251) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 513, 1.232) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 514, 1.202) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 517, 1.119) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 551, 1.080) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 552, 1.081) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 553, 1.079) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 554, 1.088) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 561, 1.072) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 562, 1.113) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 563, 1.091) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 564, 1.092) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 571, 1.089) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 572, 1.073) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 573, 1.061) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 574, 1.111) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 581, 1.119) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 582, 1.123) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 583, 1.151) ;
    cbuf_update(cb1, 584, 1.153) ;  
    cbuf_dump(cb1);
    return 0;

}
```

cbuf_dump simply prints out the information pertaining to the buffer. When using this code, I get the following output:

```
EXPANDING CIRCULAR BUFFER!

Newsize: 19
pastthe malloc
newBuffer start: 10


EXPANDING CIRCULAR BUFFER!

Newsize: 39
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see, I inserted print statements so that during runtime I could see where the code was right before it segfaulted. It is able to expand the first time, but when it tries to allocated memory a second time for a new "newBuffer", it segfaults.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we have a little bit less code? Try to minimize your problem into the smallest possible example, then update your question.

Comment: edited to only show the issue with expanding the buffer

Comment: Your final line in `cbuf_update` looks very suspicious to me.  `*cb_ptr = *newBuffer` will do weird things.  For one thing, in the previous line, you free `cb_ptr`, so assigning something to it is bad.  By using `*(ptr) = *(ptr)`, you'll be doing a bitwise copy of the objects, which may or may not be ideal.  It looks to me like you want `cbuf_update`'s first argument to be `cbuf**`, so that your final line can be `*cb_ptr = newBuffer`.  Of course, all other references to `cb_ptr` would then have to look like `*cb_ptr->`.  I'm not certain this will fix your issue, but it is a memory corruption.

Comment: Do I get bonus points for using every available character in my previous comment?  Is there a SO name for a twoosh? ;-)

Comment: I know that changing my first argument to cbuf** in cbuf_update would probably make fixing this issue a lot easier. However the prototype of the function uses cbuf* and must stay that way for this program. Basically I am trying to make a new cbuf, assign the current cbuf to the new cbuf and then free the memory that the old cbuf was using

Comment: Are you related to [user2081737](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2081737/user2081737) or taking the same class?  There's a question [Pointer not updating in `main()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914170/pointer-not-updating-in-main) about a `cbuf_update()` function, and there's also your previous question [Shrinking size of circular buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291959/c-shrinking-size-of-circular-buffer).  I'm not saying either of these questions is a direct duplicate of this one, but they seem to be related.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
*cb_ptr = *newBuffer;
```

clearly does something you don't want. You probably meant:

```
cb_ptr = newBuffer;
```

If your `cb_ptr` parameter is `in/out`, then it should be used as:

```
void cbuf_update(cbuf **cb_ptr, unsigned int time, double rate)
...
if((*cb_ptr)->freeSlots == 0){
...
    *cb_ptr = newBuffer;
...
```

And in main:

```
cbuf_update(&cb1, 60, 1.291) ;
```